# Flashed the ESP-01S to new firmware, now can't send any AT commands

Tags: arduino, esp8266, at-command, serial-communication, esp8266wifi

I've have been trying to flash the ESP-01S to the 1.5.1 from the official website. I am also using their own flash tool. The tool detects the component and completes the update all the time, this is what it detects:

```
5Eh : N/A
flash devID:
4014h
QUAD;8Mbit
crystal:
26 Mhz

AP:  CA-2B-96-03-59-AF  STA:  C8-2B-96-03-59-AF
```

Now when I try connect everything up with my arduino and try some AT commands through the serial port, nothing happens. When the ESP is first switched on it spits out the normal gibberish however, it now doesn't say "READY" and every time i send an AT command it sends no reply. 
I can still reflash the device but, no matter what I try no AT command work.

Comment: did you disconnect io 0 from ground after flashing?

Comment: Yeah I did, I removed IO0 from ground to try the AT commands

Comment: how do you power it?

Comment: External power supply on 3.3 volts.

Comment: now I remembered the problem. use DIO setting

Comment: Alright i'll give that a go.

Comment: why do you flash so old version?

Comment: I'm flashing the old one because my chip only has 1mb of flash memory and after 1.5 all the updates are for chips with 2mb. I tried flashing with DIO but also to no avail. I did however find this,

ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x40100000, len 1856, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xef
load 0x00000000, len 0, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0xef
load 0x00000000, len 0, room 0 
tail 0
chksum 0xef
csum 0xef
csum err
ets_main.c

Sorry about formatting, can't seem to get the code format to work in comments.
The above come up with the baud rate is set to 74880

Comment: 1.6 has 512+512. and here is 1 MB build of 1.7 https://github.com/loboris/ESP8266_AT_LoBo with a flashing script

Comment: Followed the instructions on the github page but, unfortunately it still doesn't work.